# Can you install a stripped-down version of linux that only runs a single, full-window app?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

Trying to take my Pi Zero W and embed it in one of my projectors to create an information appliance.  In other words, I don't need, or even want the overhead of a full desktop with window management, etc.

I've read all I should need is Linux running a X11 server, then my app--the client--would simply talk to that.  I've also heard my app can act as both the X11 server *and* client.

I've seen people talk about booting Raspbian straight into a full-screen app, but if I'm correct, that's technically still loading the full Raspbian desktop--it's just hiding it--so it's still using critical resources.

So is what I'm after possible?  A bare-bones linux install with networking, but no UI except a single window application? Things like wireless could be handled via config files, etc.  What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: You could remove X11 entirely and use an ncurses GUI... Examples of applications [here](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reviews/6964/1/) ... and [ncurses Howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.html#AWORDWINDOWS)

Comment: Have you estimated or tested if the overhead  is actually impacting your application? I would expect it is not the major bottleneck.  You should expect that the amount of effort to implement this may greatly exceed the gain you get vs just using a more powerful embedded PC. Typically this type of exercise is used to drive a **downgrade** of the controller in an embedded product to a slower or lesser featured device to save money on the *Bill of Materials*. BTW if you aren't actively using the Desktop Manager the resource use is... **minimal**

Comment: Hi @crasic!  The entire point of this endeavor is to learn how to play with a Pi. I figured if I'm going to really dig into the nuts and bolts, may as well get my hands dirty.  Great way to learn more about Linux, the Pi, X11, etc.  I already program in Windows and Mac, and on iOS and Android, and on Arduino and even Netduino.  Seemed to me like the Pi was the next logical thing to play with. And I need an information panel, so, whole flock of birds with one stone kinda thing.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with the official [Raspbian-Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) since it is already pretty much as stripped down as one could need, and works out of the box with the hardware.

By Default You Get a fully functional, light weight linux for free (time, money, freedom)

1. Kernel
2. Coreutils (Shell and basic shell tools)
3. Networking Tools (wlan and ssh)
4. System Frameworks like `python` `ruby` `perl`

> "A bare-bones linux install with networking, but no UI except a single window application? Things like wireless could be handled via config files, etc. What's the best way to approach this?"

Check! (*Note, config is already done via files, the GUI tools are just interfaces to edit config files and periodically read status files to track dynamic information*)

Only thing that you Don't get is a GUI of any sort. More on that below.

---

## GUI Options

When you write a GUI application, there are common elements that you usually need to have. E.G.

- Button (Events and Mouse Handling)
- Window/Subwindow (Overlapping Buffers)
- Tool Bar (Context Dependent Visibility)
- Text Box (
- Image

When choosing a framework, a trade-off exists between functionality that is done for you and functionality you must reinvent.

> Note: Calculating the pixels to draw for a button is simple, but to create a system that can detect and respond to all kinds of arbitrary input (click, double click, drag, swipe, scroll, etc.) is actually very very hard (read: tedious and error prone).

What follows is a brief description of a few options for bare-bones displays.

### 1. Framebuffer

The Raw Graphical Output on your screen actually is itself a file. This file is there even if `X` is not installed.

`/dev/fb0`

An description of what this thing is can be found in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt).

However, for us it is suffice to imagine this as a "bitmap" of your screen. With many caveats, because the formatting of the data is platform dependent.

Your application (written in `c`, `python`, `java`, whatever). Would open this file, and write (*Platform Dependent!*) bytes to it to display and modify an image on the display. It would also need to grab raw input from mouse and keyboard and interpret that as button clicks, and distribute events (calls) to appropriate functions.

For example

`cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb0`

Will make colorful pixels randomly populate your screen

- [Is it possible to access to the framebuffer in order to put a pixel on the screen from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192206/is-it-possible-to-access-to-the-framebuffer-in-order-to-put-a-pixel-on-the-scree)
- [How to use /dev/fb0 as a console from userspace, or output text to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20458/how-to-use-dev-fb0-as-a-console-from-userspace-or-output-text-to-it)

### 2. X Windowing System (X11 aka Xorg)

The most infamous user of framebuffer. In a nut-shell This provides

1. Windows (Possibly Overlapping Independent Regions)
2. Input (Mouse and Keyboard)
3. Events

Most people will use a higher level GUI library like `GTK` `Qt` or `wxWidgets` to create usable objects like buttons and toolbars using the basic features provided by `X`. These libraries also greatly simplify creating "event handlers" for things like buttons and key presses.

You can also directly draw graphics using `OpenGL`

**You do not need to have a full featured GUI Desktop Running or even Installed  to use X to run a graphical application**

Your application (Again, `python`, `c++`, whatever) would use the GUI Tools together with `Xlib`  (API for Xorg) to draw widgets, windows, etc. on the screen.

> NOTE: When running a Full-Screen Application with a desktop environment, there are pretty much no other GUI tools running in the background anyway, mimicking this use.

- [How do you create a window in Linux with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190925/how-do-you-create-a-window-in-linux-with-c)

### 3. Text Based User Interface (nCURSES!)

Text Based User Interfaces are a simple alternative to all of the above, and may be a cool and elegant solution to your "Information Appliance" concept.

This application uses the terminal shell directly to create visual displays with ASCII characters. The library `ncurses` is supported in many languages and provides GUI-like concepts of windows, buffers, buttons, tabs, input, etc. in a console environment

You can actually create a very simple Menu-Based Interface using just a shell script with the built-in linux utility

`dialog`

which creates the type of interface shown in the top left of the following image.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting about Raspbian Lite.  Didn't know about that.  As you said, that doesn't give you any GUI whatsoever (i.e. no 'Desktop', correct?)  As for my use, I need to draw graphic primitives and be able to scale and rotate them, but I only need rudimentary input (i.e. is a keyboard button or mouse button clicked, or even a button on a GPIO pin, but no on-screen cursor or anything like that.  The 'inputs' will be supplementary.  Think the page-turning buttons on a Kindle.  Above the person brought up Pygame. Can you use that with Raspbian Lite?

Comment: *"Can you use that with Raspbian Lite"*- Yes, its the same exact operating system, so all the same packages are supported.  the only difference is the Desktop Packages are  not installed by default, but you can turn lite version into "full" version with a single command. *"i.e. no 'Desktop', correct?"* - Correct, when the system boots you are presented with a console shell and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7r6CtPqOu0). A key point in response to your 3rd paragraph: X is implemented very differently than Windows or MacOS. It's not "all or nothing", so you never need to load "the full desktop" if you don't need it. There are several layers which can be simplistically summarized as:

1. The X window system. If you launch X with no additional layers, you get a gray background and nothing else, with no means to launch programs in the GUI. You can write startup scripts to launch programs. Typically, you'd launch a terminal (e.g. `xterm`) that you could use to launch additional programs from. You get no nice title bars or buttons to manipulate windows with.
2. A window manager. This is the layer that adds a colored desktop, title bars and buttons to manipulate windows. You can, but do not have to, add file managers, launch bars and other niceties. Things look nicer, but there's little integration between programs.
3. A desktop environment. These roll everything together, providing features like an integrated clipboard, sound management and other features that feel more like a consumer "desktop".

What I think you want is layer 2. A window manager but nothing else so you can launch a GUI program. There are some very lightweight window managers available. I chose OpenBox for the project in the video.

Of course, you could forego a GUI entirely and build it using a text interface, but if you want to take advantage of web technologies, or use GUI toolkits, you'll likely want a minimal GUI.

Wikipedia has a nice summary if you want [more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).

Answer (score 0):

I was in a quite similar case, and did choose to use `pygame`, a python binding to SDL, a graphic library.

**Good points :**
As SDL don't rely on X11, pygame can be run from console, and shows a nice fullscreen graphical application, heavily customizable (aka : you start from a black screen, then draw what you want on it)
Pygame is quite well [documented](https://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html#) and [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pygame), quite easy, offers all the base functions you will need to manage user interactions and interface in a single library.

**Bad points :**
Pygame lacks GUI content: it's up to you to draw every buttons, icons, boxes, as image files. (You still can display geometrical shapes and texts to screen just with code.)
Some user input have to be manually managed : by exemple don't expect to use a text field object "out of the box" : you will only be able to read raw keyboard press and have to edit the right button in the right page, then refresh your screen, at each press ! 
Don't worry too much about this, it's not dramatic, just a bit annoying.

If you want to give a try to pygame, take a look to [this software](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-pi-cam/blob/master/cam.py) from adafruit, it's a very good inspiration when building a GUI : 
The Button and Icon class are very well written, the page management is quite nice too.

**Alternatives**
There are other tools to write graphic interfaces running without X11, and even GPU optimized : dispmanx and openMax. They are far more difficult to work with (gpu memory management is a pain) and your client would need to be written in C/C++. Worst, these libraries lack tons of tools that pygame can provide (no user input management ..)

Comment: Funny you should mention Pygame!  I just bought the OLED Bonnet Pack for Raspberry Pi Zero from Adafruit and they specifically mentioned that since the OLED screen is only 128x64.  Plus, for my app, the HDMI will be connected to a cheap LED projector running at 320x240. If you're saying Pigame can be used for both, then that may be a win-win for me! BUT... what did you do for the OS? Did you still load up the entire Raspbian desktop?  That's the stumbling block I keep coming back to. Like taking a semi to the store to buy milk.

Comment: One other comment... I need my graphics to be rotatable via translations.  Any arbitrary angle.  Doesn't have to be high-performance.  Can even be 10FPS. Don't care. I just have to be able to rotate it for my needs.  Heck... even basic OpenGL would work.  Point being I don't need a mouse or a desktop, don't need text input or buttons or anything else.  I will read the keyboard, but just to do things like rotating the screen as we just discussed.

Comment: I can confirm it, you don't need to use the desktop,
µ

Comment: About the double output, i don't know if you can run pygame twice, or if you need to use a mirroring program (fbcp or raspi2raspi are fine).
And yes, pygame can translate or  rotate without any problems :)

Comment: To be more precise : pygame can be run on the raspbian-lite OS, and is able to process at high FPS (at least on your small screen resolutions !)